# request parameters(timestamp) for client.messages.list and client.monitor.alerts.list

Tags: twilio

I'm simply fetching data from twilio messages and alerts. But I want to fetch data for specific time range.
I noticed that we have parameters:

1. client.messages.list(date_sent_before=xxx, date_sent_after=xxx)
2. client.monitor.alerts.list(start_date=xxx, end_date=xxx)

My question is:
Data of those date there is included or excluded?

I did some tests, and it seems below case, can anybody help to confirm?

1.client.messages.list(date_sent_before=xxx, date_sent_after=xxx)
data of date_sent_before is excluded while data of date_sent_after is included.

2. client.monitor.alerts.list(start_date=xxx, end_date=xxx)
   data of start_date and end_date are included.

Comment: @Ken White, what did you write here please? It seems that I can't see your words. Could you please rewrite it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When someone changes a post, you can see that change in the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72093921/revisions) by clicking on the *edited* link. In this case, I just edited the title to remove information that was already available in the tags.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! sorry about the naive question. Do you have any idea about the question I had there, pls?

Comment: You're always welcome to ask about how the site works. As far as your question, no - I don't have an answer. If I did, I would have written one for you. :-)